# How do you extract a HTML link text node in PHP once link is clicked?

Tags: php

I am using a PHP foreach loop to list a series of links on a HTML page, which are rendered using jquery mobile.  When one of the links is chosen, I want to be able to use the link label in PHP code to query a database and generate the header and other data for the destination page.

The problem is detecting which link was chosen.  It seems that an "onclick" event would be involved, but that might mean using Javascript.  I've seen an example of placing PHP inside a HTML form, but that relies on using a submit button to create a $_POST input.  In my case, the link would be the only button involved in the event,so creating a separate Submit button would not make sense.

Answer (score 2):

You can add query parameters to the links. (e.g. `?id=foo`) and then pick them up in PHP via `$_GET['id']`.